# Knex insert multiple records only returns the first record inserted

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have this `Knex` `insert`:

```
NoteTag.createNoteTag = async (noteId, tagIds, db) => (
    db.sequelize.knex('note_tags')
      .insert(
        tagIds.map(
          tagId => ({
            note_id: noteId,
            tag_id: tagId,
          }),
        ),
      )
      .then( function() {
        return db.sequelize.knex('tags')
          .select([
            'tags.id',
            'tags.title',
            'tags.type',
          ])
          .innerJoin('note_tags', 'tags.id', 'note_tags.tag_id')
          .where('note_tags.note_id', noteId);
      })
  );
```

If I pass in an array with more than one `tagId` (e.g `[1, 2]`) an insert for each is executed and all records are created in the database but only the first record is returned so I get this:

```
"tags": {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "quality",
  "type": "product"
}
```

instead of this:

```
"tags": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quality",
    "type": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "price",
    "type": "product"
  }
]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure there are tags in the `tags` table with ids 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're mixing callbacks with async/await. Callbacks are not the same as promises (which is what async/await uses under the hood).

My guess is that the first function isn't finished when the second function runs since it's wrapped in async without using await. The second function is what is returned and is actually used by the await in the callee of this method. Since only one record had been inserted, you only get the one back. If you put `await` where needed (first and second function) that will make sure the callee await for both things to finish and to return the right value. This is just a guess - but strange things happen with non-canonical asynchronous code.

```
NoteTag.createNoteTag = async (noteId, tagIds, db) => (
    await db.sequelize.knex('note_tags')
      .insert(
        tagIds.map(
          tagId => ({
            note_id: noteId,
            tag_id: tagId,
          })
        )
      );

    const tags = await db.sequelize.knex('tags')
        .select([
            'tags.id',
            'tags.title',
            'tags.type',
        ])
        .innerJoin('note_tags', 'tags.id', 'note_tags.tag_id')
        .where('note_tags.note_id', noteId);
    });

    return tags;
  );
```